# LinkedHashMap order changed when passed to JSP as JSON

Tags: linkedhashmap

I pass a LinkedHashMap (inserted ascending order of value) to JSP as JSON(through AJAX call). When I access this JSON, I see it is ordered by key, rather than by value.  What should I do to access this ordered by value?

Comment: I have the same problem. I specifically use LinkedHashMap to keep a special order but it's gone in JSP.

Comment: Finally I sorted the list in JSP using javascript.